# Insert Row between two cells based on values

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a macro that will insert rows based on cell values in column E. If the cells above and below have a difference more than 0.002, I want two rows inserted in between. Below is an example of what I would like to have the data to look like

EX.

Column E

42948.745

**(Insert Blank (Row)**

**(Insert Blank Row)**

42948.758

**(Insert Blank (Row)**

**(Insert Blank Row)**

42948.898

42948.900

42948.901

**(Insert Blank (Row)**

**(Insert Blank Row)**

42948.933

Even better if the code included a way to fill the cells in the blank row with + 0.001 from the above cell and -0.001 from the bottom cell. Ex.

42948.901

**Insert 42948.902**

**Insert 42948.932**

42948.933

Thank you so much as I have been trying to figure this out forever. I have many shortcuts but no solutions.

Comment: VBA could do this. What have you tried? If you're new to VBA, record a marco and edit it. Just need some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do what you want

```
Sub InsertBlankRowAndSetValue()
    Dim yourColumn As String
    Dim rowToStart As Integer
    Dim nameOfYourSheet As String

    Dim currentValue As Double
    Dim previousValue As Double

    'EDIT VALUES HERE
    yourColumn = "E"
    rowToStart = 1
    nameOfYourSheet = "Name of your sheet"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nameOfYourSheet)
        'For each cell in the column from the end
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, yourColumn).End(xlUp).Row To rowToStart + 1 Step -1
            currentValue = CDbl(.Range(yourColumn & i).Value)
            previousValue = CDbl(.Range(yourColumn & i).Offset(-1, 0).Value)

            'If the difference with the previous > 0.002
            If ((currentValue - previousValue) > 0.002) Then
                'Add rows and set values
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Range(yourColumn & i).Value = currentValue + 0.001
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Range(yourColumn & i).Value = previousValue + 0.001
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Explanations

Edit the name of your sheet in `nameOfYourSheet = "Name of your sheet"` to make it work.

I go through every value in your column starting from the bottom (less problems with index when you add a row above) and if the difference is more than 0.002 then I add a row and put +0.001 as it's value.

Comment: This code works amazing for adding the blank rows. The values in the blank row are just the number 0.001 and not +0.001/-0.001 the above and below values. Thank you anyways though as the blank rows help me tremendously.

Comment: @JTolsma Sorry I misunderstood what you asked in the first place. I edited the code to do so, now the values are correct. If this code works, please accept my answer by hitting the button below the up/down vote!

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much.